# Selecting ListView item

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have created a ListView with football clubs. I would like to select an item and that it opens a new Activity with the information of selected item.

This is my ListView:

```
base.OnCreate (bundle);
        clubs = new string[] {
            "AC Milan",
            "Borussia Dortmund",
            "Chelsea London",
            "FC Barcelona",
            "Manchester United",
            "Manchester City",
            "Real Madrid"
        };

        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, clubs);
    }
```

Comment: Implement the itemClickListener or itemSelectListner according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to override `OnListItemClick` for getting selected item from ListView as :

```
protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView listview, 
                                           View view, int pos, long id)
  {
     var selectedvalue = clubs[pos];
    // start new Activity here....
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Your_Next_Activity));
    intent.PutExtra("selectedvalue", selectedvalue);
    StartActivity(intent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create OnItemClickListener
2. Get the selected item
3. start new activity with the details.